# Build Visual Studio Azure Data Factory Template

Tags: visual-studio-2015, azure-data-factory, appveyor

I have an Azure Data Factory Visual Studio Project within a GitHub repository, i want to have continuous integration build + deploy using appveyor.

when i build vith Visual Studio all are fine.[image]

I think that those command `validate json ...` are part of the visual studio tool for azure data factory, because my appveyor configuration build my other solutions projects except my `.dfproj`.

It's any way to configure appveyor to optain the complete build of my solution including json and references validation of my data factory project?

Comment: What image are you using (default or VS 2017)? Have you tried [checking with RDP](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/how-to/rdp-to-build-worker/) if there is anything missing on that AppVeyor image?

Comment: This image is from my VS 2015 ouput window, and i want to do this with appveyor.

Comment: Johan, I think you misunderstood the the question. Feodor asked you about [AppVeyor build worker image](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-environment/#build-worker-images). Also he asked to [RDP](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/how-to/rdp-to-build-worker/) to check if we have to add something to the build worker image to make it work. And 2 more questions: Can you built it locally with `msbuild` command line? Is your repo public?

Comment: well, now i understand. First question, i am using default image VS 2015. Third question, yes, i can build locally with msbuild because locally i have installed `AzureDataFactoryVisualStudioTools-VS2015.vsix`, this pluging allow `msbuild` to build(validate jsons) azure data factory project. My repo it's private.

Comment: @johanPino, did you ever solve this?

Comment: @jaspernygaard unfortunately not.